# How can I get the email addresses from a webform submission list and use them in a rule to send an email out when new content is published?

Tags: webforms, rules

My website has a webform that people can fill out to keep up with the site, I want to be able to send an email to everyone on that list when new content of certain types is published. I was planning on using a rule to do that (have it trigger when new content of those types is published), but I am not sure how to get access to the webform results in the rule to use the email addresses in creating the email.

I have looked at the [Rules Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_webform) module but it seems to only give you access to the webform data on a webform submission action not on a new content published action.

Do any of y'all know how I could get access to the webform submission data from inside a new content published rule?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried https://www.drupal.org/project/eca

Comment: @cilefen I have not, I will look into that. Thanks!